# Add Extra Strings Based on count of fields- Sed/Awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have data in below format in a text file.

```
 null,"ABC:MNO"
"hjgy","ABC:PQR"
"mn","qwe","ABC:WER"
"mn","qwe","mno","ABC:WER"
```

All rows should have 3 fields like row 3. I want the data in below format.

```
"","","","ABC:MNO"
"hjgy","","","ABC:PQR"
"mn","qwe","","ABC:WER"
"mn","qwe","mno","ABC:WER"
```

If the row starts with null then null should be replace by `"","","",`

If there are only 2 fields then `"","",`  should be added after 1st string .

If there are 3 fields then `"",` should be added after 2nd string

If there are 4 fields then do nothing.

I am able to handle 1st scenario by using  `sed  's/null/\"\",\"\",\"\"/' test.txt`

But I dont know how to handle next 2 scenarios.

Regards.

Comment: Can the field contents have `,` inside double quotes? For example: `"abc,xyz"` ?

Comment: No .. Ideally it shouldnt have . But dont know extreme scenario.

Comment: No it wont have.

Comment: When you said `All rows should have 3 fields like row 3` - you meant `All rows should have 4 fields like row 4` didn't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples only, please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  sub(/^null/,"\"\",\"\",\"\"")
}
NF==2{
  $1=$1",\"\",\"\""
}
NF==3{
  $2=$2",\"\""
}
1' Input_file
```

***OR*** make `"` as a variable and one could try following too:

```
awk -v s1="\"\"" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  sub(/^null/,s1 "," s1","s1)
}
NF==2{
  $1=$1"," s1 "," s1
}
NF==3{
  $2=$2"," s1
}
1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                 ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=","           ##Setting FS and OFS to comma here.
}
{
  sub(/^null/,"\"\",\"\",\"\"")  ##Substituting starting with space null to "","","", in current line.
}
NF==2{                 ##If number of fields are 2 then do following.
  $1=$1",\"\",\"\""    ##Adding ,"","" after 1st field value here.
}
NF==3{                 ##If number of fields are 3 here then do following.
  $2=$2",\"\""         ##Adding ,"" after 2nd field value here.
}
1                      ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Null is not getting replace .. null,"","","ABC:MNO"

Comment: @user2854333, in your shown samples null has space before it let me change it now.

Comment: @user2854333, Please try now, I have remove space before null now, please check it once and let me know how it goes, thank you.

Comment: sorry that might have been type . There are no space before null .. removed ^ and it works fine ... You are truly a genius

Comment: @user2854333, not an issue, I have taken care of it, please check it now, we should be Good here.

Answer (score 4):

With `perl`:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/^null,/"","","",/; s/.*,\K/q("",) x (3 - tr|,||)/e' ip.txt
"","","","ABC:MNO"
"hjgy","","","ABC:PQR"
"mn","qwe","","ABC:WER"
"mn","qwe","mno","ABC:WER"
```

- `s/^null,/"","","",/` take care of `null` field first
- `.*,\K` matches till last `,` in the line

  - `\K` is helpful to avoid having to put this matching portion back
  - `3 - tr|,||` will give you how many fields are missing (`tr` return value is number of occurrences of `,` here)
  - `q("",)` here `q()` is used to represent single quoted string, so that escaping `"` isn't needed
  - `x` is the string replication operator
  - `e` flag allows you to use Perl code in replacement section

If rows starting with `null,` will always have two fields, then you can also use:

```sh
perl -pe 's/.*,\K/q("",) x (3 - tr|,||)/e; s/^null,/"",/'
```

Similar logic with `awk`:

```sh
awk -v q='"",' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/^null,/, q q q);
                c=4-NF; while (c--) $NF = q $NF} 1'
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using awk:

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS }
    { gsub(/^ /,"",$1)
    if($1=="null") print "\x22\x22","\x22\x22","\x22\x22", $2
    else if(NF==2) print $1,"\x22\x22","\x22\x22",$2
    else if(NF==3) print $1,$2,"\x22\x22",$3
    else print $0 }' input
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\s*null,/"",/;:a;ta;s/,/&/3;t;s/.*,/&"",/;ta' file
```

If the line begins with `null` replace that field by an empty one i.e. `"",`.

Reset the substitute success flag by going back to `:a` using `ta` (this will only be the case when the first field is `null` and has be substituted).

If the 3rd field separator exists then all done.

Otherwise, insert an empty field before the last field separator and repeat.