# Add additional fields based on field count

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in below format in a file

```
"123","XYZ","M","N","P,Q"
"345",
"987","MNO","A,B,C"
```

I always want to have 5 entries in the row , so if the count of fields in 2 then 3 extra ("") needs to be added.

```
"123","XYZ","M","N","P,Q" 
"345","","","",""  
"987","MNO","A,B,C","",""
```

I looked upto the solution  on the page

[Add Extra Strings Based on count of fields- Sed/Awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67737116/add-extra-strings-based-on-count-of-fields-sed-awk)

which has very similar requirement but when I try it fails as I have comma (,) within the field also.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `,` at the end of second line a typo? If not, can other fields be empty too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In  GNU `awk` with your shown samples, please try following code.

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
FNR==NR{
  nof=(NF>nof?NF:nof)
  next
}
NF<nof{
  val=""
  i=($0~/,$/?NF:NF+1)
  for(;i<=nof;i++){
    val=(val?val OFS:"")s1 s1
  }
  sub(/,$/,"")
  $0=$0 OFS val
}
1
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' ' ##Starting awk program from here setting FPAT to csv file parsing here.
BEGIN{ OFS="," }                         ##Starting BEGIN section of this program setting OFS to comma here.
FNR==NR{                                 ##Checking condition FNR==NR here, which will be true for first time file reading.
  nof=(NF>nof?NF:nof)                    ##Create nof to get highest NF value here.
  next                                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
NF<nof{                                  ##checking if NF is lesser than nof then do following.
  val=""                                 ##Nullify val here.
  i=($0~/,$/?NF:NF+1)                    ##Setting value of i as per condition here.
  for(;i<=nof;i++){                      ##Running loop till value of nof matches i here.
    val=(val?val OFS:"")s1 s1            ##Creating val which has value of "" in it.
  }
  sub(/,$/,"")                           ##Removing ending , here.
  $0=$0 OFS val                          ##Concatinate val here.
}
1                                        ##Printing current line here.
'  Input_file  Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding this code here, where keeping a variable named `nof` where we can give our number of fields value which should be added minimum in all missing lines, in case any line is having more than minimum field values then it will take that value to add those many number of fields in missing field line.

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v nof="5" -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
FNR==NR{
  nof=(NF>nof?NF:nof)
  next
}
NF<nof{
  val=""
  i=($0~/,$/?NF:NF+1)
  for(;i<=nof;i++){
    val=(val?val OFS:"")s1 s1
  }
  sub(/,$/,"")
  $0=$0 OFS val
}
1
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Comment: It works .. Thank you .. Any reason why there are entries for input file?

Comment: @AnandAbhay, I am in process of writing detailed explanation. Actually code is reading files 2 times, 1st time it get maximum number of fields value and 2nd time it checks whichever line is having less fields it adds them then.

Comment: @AnandAbhay, Detailed explanation for above code is added now.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed explaination.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one for GNU awk using `FPAT` when *[you] always want to have 5 entries in the row :*

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS=","
}
{
NF=5                              # set NF to limit too long records
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # iterate to NF and set empties to ""
    if($i=="")
        $i="\"\""
}1' file
```

Output:

```
"123","XYZ","M","N","P,Q"
"345","","","",""
"987","MNO","A,B,C","",""
```

Comment: Since you need to loop anyway, doing `NF=5` first isn't actually doing anything for you in this case except adding some more work/time to the execution. Just get rid of `NF=5` and make the loop `for(i=1;i<=5;i++)` and it'll produce the same output but run a bit faster.

Comment: @EdMorton Well, I put it there to cut down records longer than 5 (as I'm using `1` for output) which I of course could replace with longer `{for(i=1;i<=5;i++){if($i=="")$i="\"\"";printf "%s%s",$i,(i==5?ORS:OFS)}}` but I wanted to keep the code short and with 3M records of OP's data the original `NF=5` version ran about 10 % faster.

Comment: I hadn't considered that there might be more than 5 fields. I wonder if the desired behavior in that case really is to remove data or if we should add null fields up to the number present - I'd think it'd be the latter as @RavinderSingh13 is doing but idk. `NF=5` would add fields if there were less than 5 but what it'd do if there were more than 5 is undefined behavior, though you are already using FPAT and it'd do what you want in gawk.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a an `awk` command that would work with any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk -v n=5 -v ef=',""' -F '","' '
{
   sub(/,+$/, "")
   for (i=NF; i<n; ++i)
      $0 = $0 ef
} 1' file

"123","XYZ","M","N","P,Q"
"345","","","",""
"987","MNO","A,B,C","",""
```

Comment: Thanks Ed. That was very good trick to make it even shorter.

Comment: There's also an alternative without a loop we could do like (untested)`allef=sprintf("%*s",n-NF,""); gsub(/ /,ef,allref); $0=$0 allef` but unless you have a thousand missing fields on the line it's hard to care :-)!

Answer (score 4):

With `perl`, assuming every field is double quoted:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/,$//; s/$/q(,"") x (4 - s|","|$&|g)/e' ip.txt
"123","XYZ","M","N","P,Q"
"345","","","",""
"987","MNO","A,B,C","",""

# if the , at the end of line isn't present
$ perl -pe 's/$/q(,"") x (4 - s|","|$&|g)/e' ip.txt
"123","XYZ","M","N","P,Q"
"345","","","",""
"987","MNO","A,B,C","",""
```

`s|","|$&|g` will search for `","` and replace it back. The return value is number of replacements, which is then used to determine how many fields have to be appended.

The `e` flag allows you to use Perl code in the replacement section.

`q` operator helps to use different delimiter for single quoted string.

---

Here's an alternate solution that creates an array and then adds empty fields if necessary.

```sh
perl -lne '@f = /"[^"]+"|[^,]+/g; print join ",", @f, qw("") x (4 - $#f)'
```

`/"[^"]+"|[^,]+/g` defines fields as double quoted strings (with no double quote inside, so escaped quotes won't work with this solution) or non `,` characters (at least one, so `,` at end of line will be ignored).

`qw("") x (4 - $#f)` determines the extra fields to be appended. `qw("")` creates an array with single element of value `""` which is then multiplied using the `x` operator.

Comment: Added an answer very similar to your last using `-a` for autosplit, which I suppose is another way to create your `@f` as `@F`

Answer (score 2):

Another perl way using `-a` for autosplit and `-F` to set the separator:

```
perl -lanF'/"*,*"/' -e 'print join ",", map "\"$_\"", @F[1..5]'
```

- `-F'/"*,*"/'` - this uses an autosplit separator of double quote optionally preceeded by commas and quotes
- `-a` uses that separator to autosplit into `@F`
- `-l` adds linebreaks to print and `-n` will process input in stream mode w/o printing unless explicitly told to
- `map "\"$_\"", @F[1..5]` takes exactly 5 fields, even undefined ones, and adds double quotes
- `print join ",", map ...` takes the results of the map above, joins into a string with commas, and prints

(Note: because each line starts with a field delimiter, I'm ignoring the empty  `$F[0]` element)

Comment: Good one, especially for avoiding number of fields calculation. But doesn't cover `,` at end of second line in OP's sample (which is probably a typo by OP).

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/"[^"]*"/&/5;t;s/$/,""/;ta' file
```

If there are 5 fields, bail out.

Otherwise, append an empty field and repeat.